# SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 automatic terminated

Tags: designer-workflow

In a specific list item, a unique workflow always terminat on start and I get the following error:

> Another instance of the same workflow with the same ActivationInfo is currently running.

But I have no other instance of this workflow on this item.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to republish the workflow and run it again?

Comment: Do you have versioning turned on?

Comment: @Roman, yes I try do this

Comment: @Andrew, no, I dont have versioning turned on